# Django template roundup scientific notation

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to convert, eg:

```
0.00282357936911 to 2.82e-03 and 0.000130076846614 to 1.30e-04
```

However, when I use the filter `{{ data|stringformat:"e" }}`, I get

```
2.823579e-03 and 1.300768e-04
```

Is there are way to roundup to 2 decimal points?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
{{ data|stringformat:".2e" }}
```

The`.<number>` syntax specifies number of decimal points. See [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) for more info.